# dynamically add linkbutton to asp.net page vb

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I'm trying to programatically add some link buttons to a page.

I'm trying to follow an example that I've seen online but can't get it to work.

I want the linkbutton to call a sub e.g. download_file(,)

As an example what I have is:

```
            Dim lb = New LinkButton()
            lb.CausesValidation = True
            lb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            lb.CommandName = "lb_Click"
            lb.CommandArgument = "test"
            lb.Text = reader("filename")
            lb.EnableViewState = True
            lb.Enabled = True

            AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf download_file

            Panel1.Controls.Add(lb)
```

Getting the button(s) to appear would be a start! Also, do I need to put them on a panel?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What event in the lifecycle is that code in?  You have to add controls dynamically, I believe, in the Init or PreInit page events.

Comment: hi, yeah I moved the code to the init pag event and the buttons now appear. Enough to get me started on them! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a postback issue. You might want to try setting a break point and seeing if this code ever gets called. I tested your code inside the click event of a button control (which automatically posts back when you click it), and it did work. However, I did take out the reader() part and I replaced "Panel1" with "Form" (this shouldn't make a difference).

Also, if you're adding your panel dynamically, make sure you add it to the page's controls as well.

Answer (score 0):

write the code inside init method.